# Where to implement callback in ribbon xml with Access

Tags: ms-access, callback, ribbon

I created a ribbon xml in Access 2010, one of the related element as follows:

```
 <button id="button1" size="normal" label="Sample1" getImage="GetImage" onAction="OnMenuAction" />
```

I implemented OnAction in Main module as:

```
 Public Sub GetImage(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByRef image)
     image = "HappyFace"
 End Sub

 Public Sub OnMenuAction(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
     MsgBox "You've clicked the button " & control.ID & " on the Ribbon"
 End Sub
```

The Tab did appear in ribbon, but without "HappyFace" image and shows error message:

"Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'GetImage'.
Make sure the macro or function exists and takes the correct parameters."

When I click the button, Access also can't find the callbacks and shows the Message:

"Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'OnMenuAction'.
Make sure the macro or function exists and takes the correct parameters."

My question is where should I put these callbacks besides Main module? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by including Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library.